# Flutter App only runs when anti virus is disabled

Tags: flutter

```
    admin@DS1 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/app
$ flutter run
Multiple devices found:
Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.739]
Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.115
Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 102.0.1245.44
[1]: Windows (windows)
[2]: Chrome (chrome)
[3]: Edge (edge)
Please choose one (To quit, press "q/Q"): 3
Launching lib\main.dart on Edge in debug mode...
Failed to bind web development server:
SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
, errno = 10013), address = localhost, port = 0
#0      _NativeSocket.bind (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:996:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      WebAssetServer.start (package:flutter_tools/src/isolated/devfs_web.dart:205:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      WebDevFS.create (package:flutter_tools/src/isolated/devfs_web.dart:732:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      ResidentWebRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/isolated/resident_web_runner.dart:285:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      asyncGuard.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:111:24)
<asynchronous suspension>

Failed to bind web development server:
SocketException: Failed to create server socket (OS Error: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
, errno = 10013), address = localhost, port = 0
```

I am already checked with defining the port and hostname as well but the problem is still and only runs the app while the antivirus is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the problem and the problem is system firewall blocked the internet access for the following applications.

`dart.exe` and `git-remote-https.exe`

So, I've add the both exe files in system firewall and allow the internet access for them.

To resolve the issue find the below `.exe` files and add them to the firewall and also allow internet access to them.

Path of dart.exe: `drive://flutter_dir/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart.exe`

Path of git-remote-https.exe: `C://Program Files/git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https.exe`

Comment: is it only done from the user side? Is there any optimal solution which can be done by developer?